# React-Redux connect not working

Tags: react-redux

I am trying to use React+Redux in my codepen pen, but the connect is not injecting the prop,

Maybe its because being an amateur, I'm missing something. Please have a look.
http://codepen.io/sahil28v/pen/EKEKME?editors=0010

```
const { Component } = React;
const { createStore, bindActionCreators, applyMiddleWare, combineReducers } =     Redux;
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;

const Application = () =>  (
        <div className="ground">
    <Tmap />
        </div>
    );

class Tmap extends Component {
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  console.log(this.props.mapstate);  // This is returning undefined,no idea why
  console.log(store.getState().mapstate); // Though this returns val: "hey" as it should properly though.
 }
 render () {
  return (
   <div>

   </div>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
mapstate: state.mapstate
});

connect(mapStateToProps)(Tmap);

const initialState = {
  val: "hey"
}

const mapReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
 return state ;
} ;

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  mapstate: mapReducer,
});

const store = createStore(rootReducer);

React.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Application />
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Also,,, can I configure store over here in codepen itself for using redux devtools(chrome extension).
I tried adding ...window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f , to the create store but that doesn't work.

While somebody is answering -- can you also recommend good documentation/video for: 
->learning ES6 ...

-- Thanks for the help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Connect returns a new instance of the component I suppose. This works, using connect as a decorator.

```
@connect(
  state => ({
    mapstate: state.mapstate 
  })
)
class Tmap extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    alert(this.props.mapstate);  // This is returning undefined,no idea why
    alert(store.getState().mapstate); //As I understand this is the direct low level api which connect is meant to abstract away along with store.subscribe.
  }

  render () {
    return (
    <div>
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, Yes it does brings the state in as a prop but does that mean I'd need to add @connect(...) before every class & would it subscribe to store changes too ?. How would a mapDispatchToProps work in that case.  Also isn't this react-redux.min.js job --> It seems to work fine in local environment. There must be something I'm missing which is not making it click.

Comment: Technically yes. But you would rather `connect` a few container components. `connect` takes `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps `, then, you can use it that way `@connect(state => ({ ... }), dispatch => ({ addTodo: (value) => dispatch(addTodo(value)) })) and in an `actions` file, describe the `addTodo` function: const addTodo = value => dispatch(...).   (sorry for the indentation)

Comment: I'm happy accepting your answer ,since adding connect as a decorator does indeed injects the state as prop which was the issue to begin with when I posted. Although I'm still intrigued regarding why the connect(mapStateToProps)(ComponentName) didn't work when I did import the react-redux.min.js .  Please share your view as to why it didn't work if you can. Again, thanks for the help.

Comment: hi Guillaume , I don't know much about @ decorators--- would it work only with babel ? Or can I use it without it too. Is it something i.e ES6 or ES7 specific. My apologies, but I just had to ask this out of curiousity :)

Comment: `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` returns a function that takes a class and return another class. Decorators just makes it easier to read. Instead of using the decorator, you could have done `const newComponent = connect(mapPropsToState)(Tmap)` or https://gist.github.com/GuillaumeBadi/01cb8e0ac64317ad8c40c15f517ba2ef.

Comment: Yes at the moment, you have to use babel sadly

Answer (score 6):

You have forgotten to save the result of connect into a new variable. And this new variable is what you should use instead of Tmap.

```
const CTmap = connect(... 
.... 
<CTmap/>
```

Comment: - hi Leif , thanks for that , but I realized earlier after Guillaume's reply :). Good thing though , I got to know about @ symbol and its use .

Comment: Ah yes,... Now I see your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem, I resolve it below !

First, you should export `connect` output object like below ↓

```
class Tmap extends Component { ... }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Tmap);
```

then, and then in `routes` add exported object instead of class, like ↓

```
import TmapConnectOutput from './Components/Tmap';
export const routes = <Layout>
    <Route exact path='/Tmap' component={TmapConnectOutput as any} />
</Layout>;
```

Comment: Where did `TmapConnectOutput ` come from?

Answer (score 1):

Do not export the `function` or `class`

Export the `connector` class

```
//don't use export here
function ProductCounterPage(props) {
    const {
        ProductItem,
        OrderItemList,
        onCountChange,
        ...rest
    } = props;
    ...............
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(ProductCounterPage);
```